# How can I send multiple images next to text content to a Discord Channel using Python?

Tags: python, image, discord, inline

I need to do something similar to this:

[Bot screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Az21.png)

How would I accomplish? It doesn't look like Pillow or similar has been used to stitch multiple images together as the heights of the icons look different. Plus, the images are contiguous with the markdown text. All I have seen in the Discord/Python documentation suggests it can't be done but obviously can! I don't believe embeds are being used, either.

Comment: As i saw the screenshot i found thats not an image it is a custom emoji.

Comment: You are correct. It’s a series of independent emojis actually.